# Different domain per node

Tags: domain-access

I wonder if it is possible to have different domains set for, for instance, per path basis, or view basis, or node id basis?

Answer (score 0):

[Domain Access](http://www.drupal.org/project/domain) is great module that allows you to different domains set for instance, per path basis, or view basis, or node id basis.

`The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database`.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I know about the Domain Access, but haven't found specifically if it supports the mentioned requirements (path, node id, view).